# Understanding how Docker volumes work with compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In the Docker Compose example for WordPress, the Ycode listing [1] says:

```
volumes:
   - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
```

What is exact meaning here? To compare, while using the Docker client, you can map volume to a host folder [2]:

```
-v /src/webapp:/webapp
```

> This command mounts the host directory, `/src/webapp`, into the container at `/webapp`.

[1] https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/#define-the-project

[2] https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#locate-a-volume

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`db_data:/var/lib/mysql` simply means that the `db_data` volume that was previously created will be made available in the container at `/var/lib/mysql`.

In you example it's created at the very end of the compose file.
From the Docker documentation: "The docker volume db_data persists any updates made by Wordpress to the database."

Compose volumes works the same way as the Docker engine.

In you case db_data is just a named volume instead of a path like your second example.

Comment: so in this case there is no host mapping, and Docker knows that db_data is so to say a link between Wordpress container and the /var/lib/mysql folder in the db container?

Comment: Host mapping and volumes are two different things. db_data is not an host nor a container, it's a named volume.

Remember that the named volumed is declared at the end of the copose file.  
You are just linking a volume inside a container, that's all.

Comment: I think, I used an ambigous wording for "host mapping" - I meant "mapping to a host folder"

Comment: I see, actually you have the volumes, that does the "mapping to a host folder" part and you have links, that does the "DNS mapping" part.